# Conversion by standalone fails when compiling using lualatex

Tags: luatex, standalone

This code works fine with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    $y=mx+c$
\end{document}
```

however, when compiling using `lualatex`, it fails showing up an error

> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    $y=mx+c$
\end{document}
```

knowing that I am using Texlive on Win10 x64.

Comment: The newest `standalone` version v1.3a from 2018-03-26 fixes this problem. Should be part of MikTeX soon. As TeXLive 2017 is already frozen either wait for TeXLive 2018 or install the [TDS file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/standalone.tds.zip) manually.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks for letting me know. Now working flawlessly!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `standalone` is still using `\write18` for shell escape.  Just don't use `standalone`, it's broken in too many places (in my opinion).

You can trick `standalone` into thinking that traditional shell escape is available.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\RequirePackage{shellesc}
\newcount\pdfshellescape
\pdfshellescape=1 % unrestricted shell-escape
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    $y=mx+c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. For your statement `Just don't use standalone`, what else can I use for cropping the output and converting it to different image files?

Comment: I usually use `\documentclass{article}\pagestyle{empty}` to compile, then I crop using `pdfcrop` and finally I convert to png using `mutool draw`.  But I'm on Linux, so I just have shell script for all those steps.

Comment: Henri, @Diaa: Alternative opinion: Don't use LuaTeX as it is broken in too many places. ;-) It's LuaTeX's fault to not be backwards compatible not the one of packages. On the other hand: The update to use `shellesc` in `standalone` is already in the code repository and will be part of the next release (which indeed got quite delayed as I'm quite busy otherwise).

Comment: Henri, @Diaa: I pushed the new version to CTAN yesterday. It is live there already and should be installable with the distributions in the next 1-2 days.